# Equal equations or Expressions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

I would like to check if equation (Sigmaa22) is the same as equation (stress)
Basically i have 2 equations one is called Sigmaa 22 and the other one is called stress,My problem when i try to check if the are equal to each other it showes me False although I solved them manually and they are the same ,So anyone knows how to check it on Wolfram Mathematica?

[image]

```
SF = {BesselK[1,r/c] (-8 b^2 (n - 1) + 4 c^2 + r^2) + 
     2 c r BesselK[0,r/c] -> 
    BesselK[1,r/
      c] ( (-8 b^2 (n - 1) + 4 + r^2/c^2) + (2 r BesselK[0, r/c])/(
       c BesselK[1, r/c]))};
Expand[Sigmaa22 == 
        Simplify[(Subscript[\[Sigma], o]/2)*(1 - 
             Cos[2*\[Theta]]) - ((-Subscript[\[Sigma], o])*r^2)/(2*r^2) + ((-6*((r^4*Subscript[\[Sigma],o]*(BesselK[1, r/c]*(8*b^2*(n - 1) + 4*c^2 + r^2) +2*c*r*BesselK[0, r/c]))/(4*BesselK[1, r/c]*(-(8*b^2*(n - 1)) + 4*c^2 + r^2) + 8*c*r*BesselK[0, r/c])))/r^4 + (6*((4*b^2*(n - 1)*r^2*Subscript[\[Sigma],o]*((4*c^2 + r^2)*BesselK[1, r/c] + 
                      2*c*r*BesselK[0, r/c]))/
                              (BesselK[1, 
                      r/c]*(-(8*b^2*(n - 1)) + 4*c^2 + r^2) + 
                    2*c*r*BesselK[0, r/c])))/r^4)*Cos[2*\[Theta]] - 
          2*((((8*b^2*c*(n - 1)*r*
                   Subscript[\[Sigma], 
                    o])/(BesselK[1, 
                     r/c]*(-(8*b^2*(n - 1)) + 4*c^2 + r^2) + 
                   2*c*r*BesselK[0, r/c]))*Cos[2*\[Theta]])/(c*r))*
                   (((3*c)/r)*BesselK[0, r/c] + (1 + (6*c^2)/r^2)*BesselK[1, r/c])] /. SF]
     Expand[stress == 
       Subscript[\[Sigma], 
         o]*(1 + (2*
             Cos[2*\[Theta]])/(1 + ((1 - n)*(b^2/c^2))/(4 + 
                r^2/c^2 + (2*r*BesselK[0, r/c])/(c*BesselK[1, r/c]))))]
    Sigmaa22 === stress
```

Comment: You have forgotten to define `SF` in your post.

Comment: okay i add SF it is just a rule for more simplification

Comment: I think you probably meant to *define* sigma2 and stress in your expression, but you used `==` which is used to test equality, not to set a variable value. Furthermore, you then made the comparison with `===` (`SameQ`), which is used for structural identity rather than for mathematical comparison. Try using `=` to store the values and `==` to compare the. You may also need to `Simplify` the comparison to see if it holds.

Comment: @MarcoB ,I did all u mentioned but still shows the terms are not equal to each other i just want to prove  both terms are the same but it shows False  although I solved them manually and they are the same.

Comment: @Ibrahim The function ```===``` only checks whether the two given expressions are _exactly_ the same Mathematica expressions (without applying any transformations). But we can also check that ```Sigma22``` cannot be transformed into ```stress```, as they are not the same numerically: ```{stress, Sigmaa22} /. 
  {r -> 1, c -> 2, b -> 3, \[Theta] -> 4, n -> 5, 
 Subscript[\[Sigma], o] -> 6}// N``` gives ```{8.00264, 5.57582}```